APK-installed app is not visible in other users except admin user after upgrade to Android 14
I usually install several APKs necessary for my work. They are internally released, so they are not available over Google Play.
We have several users on the device, so multiple users can use their own profiles. However, after recent updates, these apps disappear from other user accounts. And it seems there is no way to install them. More annoying, one app is still visible in the other user accounts, but it cannot be opened. It flashes and then exits.
Can anyone share some experience on how to fix this problem, or maybe in Android 14, the APK-installed app cannot be used by other users by design?

Just verifying that the apps become missing from the device app list instead of just the home screen app. For the app which appears and disappears what does the adb logcat say. How are the APKs deployed normally (website, special app, etc.) You may want to investigate if your devices are running Enterprise Mobility Management (EMM) software and a recent setting has blocked them.

nope, it really not available. And now it seems I need to actually install the apk for all users separately. Which is really annoying.
